# How to pass total amount with order details in payeezy demo payment gateway

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payeezy

I have integrated payeezy payment gateway for one of my e-commerce site. I can easily pass the order details with price and quantity but not able to pass the total amount for the order details.

Here is the code which I am using---->

```
<form action="https://demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/pay" id="pay_now_form_1dcc971562" method="post">
        <input name="x_login" type="hidden" value="XXX-XXXX-xxxxxxxxxx" />
        <input name="x_show_form" type="hidden" value="PAYMENT_FORM" />
        <input name="x_fp_sequence" type="hidden" value="14605299651823126780" />
        <input name="x_fp_hash" type="hidden" value="PNB-1.0-eba46929895e57fc4254e9ef11cdbcbcf647334c" />
        <input name="x_amount" type="hidden" />
        <input name="x_currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
        <input name="x_test_request" type="hidden" value="TRUE" />
        <input name="x_relay_response" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input name="donation_prompt" type="hidden" />
        <input name="button_code" type="hidden" value="Pay Now mySite" />
        <?php 
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item) {
            ?>
        <input name="x_line_item" value="1<|><?php echo $item['title']; ?><|><?php echo $item['title']; ?><|>1<|><?php echo $item['price']; ?><|>YES" type="hidden"> 
        <?php 
        } ?>
        <div class="cpwrap">
            <button type="button" >Pay Now</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

If do I pass the value in 
`<input name="x_amount" type="hidden" value="99"/>`

then I am getting error "Unable to proceed with payment " in the paymant gateway.

So how to resolve this issue. Please do some needful.

Thanks in advance.

with regards,
Sudhir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes.. Finally after doing lot of research on payeezy got this [link](https://support.payeezy.com/hc/en-us/articles/204011429-Sample-Code-Creating-a-Pay-Button-to-use-with-a-Hosted-Payment-Page)

Here is the code how to integrate payeezy with PHP with dynamic order details and total amount.